# The Beta badge = stack overflow was a private beta?

Tags: discussion

The badge Beta was awarded to apparently 119 people. That means that this was a private beta once.

But it was the **first** SE, existing before Stack Exchange.

How?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191791/regarding-the-beta-badge-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[On August 1st, 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/08/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/)...

> We're beginning the Stack Overflow private beta.
>
> I am sending out emails to the first 100 people for the private Stack Overflow beta; the email contains the password necessary to log in, as well as a link to this post. I will continue to email 100 people per day until all ~500 people on the private beta list have invites.

Then [on September 15th, 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/then-a-miracle-occurs-public-beta/)

> Our heartfelt thanks to all the software developers who so patiently helped us test the site during the private beta. You are the true heroes of this project, contributing your time in creating over 8,500 questions in a month and a half -- not to mention putting up with our bugs and errors. Your beta badges are forthcoming.

The nature of beta sites - and the beta badge - has changed many times over the years... But the notion of a private beta, a period where the most enthusiastic folks can test and build, has been with us from the start.

Comment: Did area 51 (the site) or stack overflow come 1st?

Comment: @bleh: A51 came along [almost two years later](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52006/274165).

Comment: Dang! what was the next se?