# Any "category of consideration" for a badge that is unattainable?

Tags: feature-request, badges

There is the `Enthusiast` silver badge

[image]

As long as I'm working in software - I am pretty much a daily SO visitor/participant.

However I make it a point to completely disconnect from computers once a week for at least 24 hours.  Therefore, this is a badge I can't ever get.  Is there some way to .. say hide it .. so it is not something I am to go after?

Not a big deal of course - just curious.  Thanks

Comment: If you'd be working in software you'd be able to write tool that imitates activity... Not that I'm suggesting to find/create one or use it...

Comment: Yea, but as you imply it's not exactly *"above board"* to get the badge that way. SO is good to me, I want to be *legit* back. I don't want a badge I have to hack to get .. unless maybe that's the purpose of the badge :)

Comment: Considering they don't hide badges that no one can ever get ever again (e.g., [Beta badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313414/215552)), I don't think they'll hide badges you just don't want to get.

Answer (score 3):

You can still get the badge. The clock "resets" at 0:00 UTC/GMT/Zulu Time. You could come on at 1:00 GMT on March 17, go away for 24 hours, then log back in again between 1-2 GMT March 18. This would "count" as two separate, continuous days of activity.

The cutoff point is useful for more than just badges. I am in the US/New York time zone, and here, UTC 0:00 comes in the evening. Run out of votes? Just wait until 7 or 8 PM (depending on DST status), and get another day's worth.

Comment: And make sure to keep this schedule up for 14 weeks to get the "Fanatic" badge.